# Azure Synapse , REPLICATED TABLE

Tags: azure, replicate, azure-synapse

I Create a small dummy table(with 1728 rows) with Distribution as "REPLICATE"
"

```
Create table complaints_stg.Employee4
with
(
clustered columnstore index,
Distribution = REPLICATE
)
as
select * from #abc
```

"

but when i do " DBCC PDW_SHOWSPACEUSED("complaints_stg.Employee4") , i do not get the same rowcount in all 60 worker nodes(some nodes have ROWS as 142 , some 60 , some have 0) . But the expection with REPLICATE distribution is that it will send all rows to all nodes , so that there is no Data movement for such small tables across nodes

Any idea why ?